# how to calculate the sum of 2 cells in a column with a different row value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

Below is my data frame:

```
   Col A   ColB   Col C   Col D   ColE
1  BBB     2100   2200    2300    2300
2  AAA     1750   1750    1800    1900

3  DDD     140      140     140     140
4  CCC     90       90      90      90
```

Output

```
    Col A   ColB   Col C   Col D   ColE
1  BBB     2100   2200    2300    2300
2  AAA     1750   1750    1800    1900

3  DDD     140      140     140     140
4  CCC     90       90      90      90

5  RRR    2,190.00   2,290.00    2,390.00    2,390.00
```

I need to calculate(sum) values of "BBB" with "DDD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the first column, subset the rows by the values `%in%` column1, remove that column and get the `colSums`

```
rbind(df1, c("Col A" = "RRR", 
        as.list(colSums(df1[df1$"Col A" %in% c("BBB", "DDD"),-1]))))
#   Col A ColB Col C Col D ColE
#1   BBB 2100  2200  2300 2300
#2   AAA 1750  1750  1800 1900     
#3   DDD  140   140   140  140
#4   CCC   90    90    90   90
#5   RRR 2240  2340  2440 2440
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Col A` = c("BBB", "AAA", "DDD", "CCC"), ColB = c(2100L, 
 1750L, 140L, 90L), `Col C` = c(2200L, 1750L, 140L, 90L), `Col D` = c(2300L, 
 1800L, 140L, 90L), ColE = c(2300L, 1900L, 140L, 90L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
```

"2", "3", "4"))